# How does the Instagram Recent Tags API endpoint work?

Tags: instagram-api

I am sending this request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=<token>&count=10
```

Which gets me this response:

```
{
  "data": [],
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "pagination": {
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  }
}
```

Why am I getting an empty media array? There is #nofilter-tagged data for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Now I know: It's because of the Sandbox mode.